# Homebrew Mac M1 can't find installs

Tags: c, installation, homebrew, homebrew-cask, cunit

I just switched to a M1 MacBook Air and I'm having trouble with Homebrew. The installation went fine I think, and then I added it to my path with the given commands:

```
Run these two commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:

    echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/xxx/.zprofile
    eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

I also did `brew install cunit` and then when I typed `brew list` CUnit was listed there so I'm assuming the brew install of cunit worked.

But when I run my C test code this is what I get:

```
test/test.c:3:10: fatal error: 'CUnit/Basic.h' file not found
#include <CUnit/Basic.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [test_compile] Error 1
```

I have been sitting with this for three days, called Apple support, searched every page related to this and still can't find a solution that works.

Has anyone had the same problem? PLEASE help

Answer (score 7):

Homebrew [installs into /opt/homebrew](https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/) by default on M1 Macs, and no longer links into `/usr/local` by default (to prevent clashes with Rosetta library installs). This means that include files and libraries can't be found without explicitly telling the compiler/linker where your Homebrew packages are installed.

The easiest way of doing this is by setting the `CPATH` environmental variable before compiling:

```
export CPATH=/opt/homebrew/include
```

Add the above line to your shell profile (`.zprofile` for zsh, or `.bash_profile` for bash) and it will be used in all future compilations.

For dependencies which also require shared libraries, you will need to also signpost the location of Homebrew's new `lib` path:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib
```